# Term for Selecting a column in linq using brackets

Tags: c#, linq

In linq what is it called when I am selecting things by using the `t1["col"]` as in:

```
var test= ((from t1 in items.AsEnumerable()
select new
{
    reference_id = t1["id"]
}
)).Distinct().ToDataTable();
```

What is it when it is:

```
t1.Field<string>("procfee")
Or
t1.procfee
```

I can't find the terms, I was thinking for the first it was dynamic or anon, but that isn't it. I am having some trouble with doing a group / sum and most all the examples I find use a more static definition such as `t1.id`, but I don't build classes for most of the data I am working with so can't use that. Without knowing what the term is I am having a hard time finding a solution for my problem.

I am having trouble with this where it returns the error: `'System.FormatException' in mscorlib.dll Input string was not in a correct format.` on the Sum() column. If I remove it, it works. The column is a text field in a DataTable

```
var ProceduresWithSum = ((from t1 in items.AsEnumerable()
                      group t1 by t1["reference_id"]  into g
    let row = g.First()
    select new {                                            
        reference_id = g.Key,
        stuff= @"{""total_fee"":""" + g.Sum(r => Convert.ToInt32(r.Field<string>("fee"))) + 
                     @""",""code"":""" + row.Field<string>("code") + 
                     @""",""description"":""" + row.Field<string>("description")  +
                     @"""}"    
    }
)).Distinct().ToDataTable();
```

Comment: `["x"]` is an indexer, if that's what you mean. If Convert.ToInt32() doesn't like whatever is returned by `r.Field<string>("fee")` at some point, *find out* what is returned by `r.Field<string>("fee")` at that point. At some point, it's either null, or something else that can't be converted to an int32.

Comment: To clarify: The problem is that you have a column which contains something (string? decimal? float? double?) that may or may not be convertible to integers after stringification, but you wrote code which presumes that every value in the column can be converted to in integer. A null can't be converted to Int32. "10.05" can't be converted to Int32. If there's a decimal point and no nulls or blanks, just use `Convert.ToDecimal()`. If it's actually decimal or double, use `r.Field<decimal>("fee")` or `r.Field<double>("fee")`.

Comment: Thank you Ed, above this when building the DataTable I have `fee = String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)t1["fee"]) ? "0" : t1["fee"]`. The data source is the results of a SQL query that returns JSON results, which I then convert back to a DataTable using `(DataTable) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(TableData, (typeof(DataTable)))`. The column is a string, but it holds Decimal values. You were right on with needing to convert to Decimal rather than Int32, While I was reviewing data I didn't see any decimals at first.

Comment: If you were looking for a query example that utilized the `indexer` style, what would you add to your search terms?

Comment: That has nothing to do with the query. There's nothing to search for. It's the same thing: `dr["fee"]` returns the value of the "fee" column cast to `object`. `dr.Field<string>("fee")` returns it cast to `string`. And it *is* cast, not converted: `dr.Field<decimal>("fee")` will throw an exception if the type of the "fee" column is actually string.

Comment: Here's [the documentation on the indexers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.item?view=netframework-4.8) for DataRow (there are multiple overloads). Here's the [documentation for `Field<T>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowextensions.field?view=netframework-4.8) and its overloads, which look a lot like the overloads on the DataRow indexer.